# ADT with Eclipse 'run' option does not display options

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I installed Eclipse with ADT from the Android Developer site (ADT Build: v21.1.0-569685) using the specified procedure. I built the example project described in the Get Started section including creating a Virtual Device. When I click on 'RUN - EXTERNAL TOOLS - RUN AS' I get (None Available). I am sure I followed all the steps as suggested. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you hit "Run" when one of your ".java" files is pulled up in the editor in Eclipse. Eclipse won't run a project when one of your xml pages is pulled up in the editor. Just a little thing that could be contributing to the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: select your project in eclipse and do Project --> Clean and then right click your project, select --> Run as --> Android Application. This should work. Ensure that you've emulator is up and running